# ftp read() Memory Error in python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

i get an error 'Memory Error' when it open and reads a file larger than 500mb.
if its less than 500mb it works perfectly..
im using the size for my progress bar's maxvalue

```
    self.ftp = FTP(hostname)
    self.ftp.login(user, password)
    self.f = open(self.filename,'rb')

    with open(self.filename,'rb') as filein:
        self.size = filein.read()

    self.size = len(self.size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `read()` method since it reads the whole file into a string. You should use the `os.stat()` function to get the the file metadata, which returns a stat structure with the member `st_size`. That's the size in bytes of the file. You don't have to read it all in first.

For sending, also read in and write out in chunks (say 16kB), in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

So, filein.read() actually reads (i.e. downloads) the file and is consuming your memory.
You can instead use

```
self.size = self.ftp.size(self.filename)
```

Comment: thx karmakaze for the reply, ive tried your code but it gives me this error

    self.size = self.ftp.size(self.filename)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ftplib.py", line 546, in size
    resp = self.sendcmd('SIZE ' + filename)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ftplib.py", line 243, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ftplib.py", line 218, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 File not found

Comment: 'File not found' hmm. Are you supplying an absolute filename beginning with '/' and if not check the 'current dir' of the ftp session.

Comment: yes the file is in the same directory.. Ive just replace the ## with open(self.filename,'rb') as filein:
        self.size = filein.read()##  with your code